# Google Safe Browsing detect Zimbra as phishing (or deceptive) site

Tags: google, zimbra

Since today, a (relatively old) Zimbra installation of a specific customer is detected by Google Safe Browsing as a phishing/deceptive site, with the classical red screen and all.

We suspect an email account was compromised and sent some small amount of spam, but is this sufficient to explain the site listing in Safe Browsing? Unfortunately, I can not find many informations on Google's site tools regarding the ban's root cause.

Any advise on how to unban it?

EDIT: I already checked for RBLs, and none lists the IP address of this Zimbra installation.

Answer (score 1):

check your blacklisting URL here [here](https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)
I would suggest check your MX record blacklisting status also put your login URL there, you will definitely get any clue

Comment: Good idea, but I already checked for it ;) Anyway, +1